# Django redis won't work on windows or in Ubuntu production

Tags: reactjs, django, redis, channel

I have React-Django application (I am using Django Rest Framework) and I am trying to integrate websockets with the channels & channels-redis package from django. I follow this [tutorial](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploying.html) along with this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVH05S1qab8) but I make adjustments based on the former when necesary.

I've installed

```
pip install channels
pip install channels-redis
```

but redis doesn't seem to work at all for me on my Windows OS

On the local server I've got the following configurations:

settings.py

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = "mysite.asgi.application"
.
.
.

if config('CHANNEL_LAYERS') == 'redis':
  CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
      "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
      "CONFIG": {
        "hosts": [os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')],
      },
    },
  }
else:
  CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
      "BACKEND": "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer",
    },
  }
```

asgi.py

```
import os
import django

from django.conf.urls import url
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "trike.settings")

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter

# Models
from logistics.consumers import OrderConsumer
django.setup()

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # Django's ASGI application to handle traditional HTTP requests
    "http": get_asgi_application(),

    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
      URLRouter([
        url(r"^order_update/$", OrderConsumer.as_asgi()),
      ])
    ),
})
```

Orders.js

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let wsStart = 'ws://'
    if (window.location.protocol === 'https:') {
      wsStart = 'wss://'
    }
    let endpoint = wsStart + window.location.host
    setSocket(new WebSocket(endpoint+'/order_update/'))
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(socket)
    if (socket) {
      socket.onmessage = function(e){
        console.log('message', e)
        const data = JSON.parse(e.data)
        syncOrder({ data })
      }
      socket.onopen = function(e){
        console.log('open', e)
      }
      socket.onerror = function(e){
        console.log('error', e)
      }
      socket.onclose = function(e){
        console.log('close', e)
      }
    }
  }, [socket]);
```

**So locally, I can only get my channels to work on InMemoryChannelLayer**. Might also be cause by having Windows OS. But I've tried installing [this](https://github.com/rgl/redis/downloads) and redis-server would run but I think had some compatibility issues. That was yesterday, now the server won't run with an Error 1069: logon failure.

**In production**, I still couldn't get it to work. I have an Ubuntu based server, and the tutorial I followed had redis working on Mac OS, which I think is Linux based (same syntax). I followed installations of channels and channels-redis package, and had the configuration above, but still won't work. I get this error:

```
WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

on the tutorial it was mentioned to run protocol servers entering this:

```
daphne -p 8001 myproject.asgi:application
```

but I get an error:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Now I am stuck with making Redis work on Ubuntu or in my local Windows OS. Can't find solutions that works online, and have posted here.

Comment: I don't know about a lot of the other technologies, but I have seen the AppRegistryNotReady when a model is imported before django.setup().  Is `from logistics.consumers import OrderConsumer` importing a model?  Can you move it to the other side of the django.setup()?

Comment: Yes still doesn't work. Same error:  Multiple exceptions: [Errno 10061] Connect call failed ('::1', 6379, 0, 0), [Errno 10061] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 6379)

Comment: Okay I did what you said on production settings and it helped to launch daphne

Comment: can you give a stack trace so we can at least have some context please.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what a stack trace is. I have a server running on nginx and gunicorn and I don't have logs like when running runserver on a local machine. If you have advice on that as well, it would help.